# Burning music problem

Tags: music, toshiba-satellite

Im using a toshiba lap top, im trying to burn a music cd, had problem with Brasero would recognise DVD+R but not burn now using K3b and it wont recognise the CD at all. It spins up but wont burn,

Comment: Think its something to do with permission, how do I give myself permission to burn?

Comment: brasero is known to not work sometimes. try using xfburn instead

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and run:

```
sudo adduser ${USER} cdrom
```

Log out, then log in. If it was a permission related issue, this should fix it.

I can't remember for sure if this is the correct group that controls access to optical devices in Ubuntu but I think I'm close.

If it isn't a permission issue and you're 100% sure it isn't a wrong media you're using, please try to run k3b from the terminal by just typing

```
k3b
```

Many applications, including k3b, when run from the terminal print out verbose debugging information that's often very useful in figuring out what the problem is, if the application's UI isn't helpful in pointing out the problem.

If you manage to do that, please copy and paste the output from the terminal into your question.

Comment: Its just spinning up then stopping, its saying it recognises the disc but wont let me burn.

Comment: No need to paraphprase, I understood that from your question :) What's new?

Comment: dev/sro 666 root.cdrom

Comment: Did you try what I recommended?

Comment: It didnt work sorry, KDE-K3B-Finish-Error.ogg

Comment: What does the command `groups` output?

Comment: its saying removable volume not mounted yet

Comment: I can't open the empty disc in the file manager

Comment: I was going to test to see if I could transfer files copy and paste, but it wont open

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not sure you actually ran the command from the terminal correctly, given your responses. If you can update your question to show exactly what you did and what the command's output was, then we might get somewhere. Especially that `groups` command would never print such output.

Comment: adm cdrom sudo audio dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OCEImPbEMgg&feature=youtu.be&hd=1

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll need to pass. I feel like we're having separate conversations. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

sudo chmod 4711 /usr/bin/cdrdao

sudo chmod 4711 /usr/bin/wodim

sudo chmod 0755 /usr/bin/growisofs

Copy and paste this into the terminal. Its a workaround as it is a bug in Ubuntu 18.04